# How to load css.erb files through asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I want my stylesheet to stay plain css but I want to use embedded ruby to include some dynamic paths to images:

```
.home {background: #FFF url(<%= image_path 'hippopotamus.jpg' %>) no-repeat; }
```

If I change the stylesheet from .css to .css.erb the `image_path` gets interpreted correctly, but it doesn't got processed by the asset pipeline when I deploy to production. If I hard code the path in, it will be wrong either in production or development because they load assets differently.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: How do you deploy your project to production server? Do you use `capistrano` and its `load "deploy/assets"` command?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm very new to deploying Rails apps and I haven't installed/learned Capistrano yet. For now I'm just pulling the changes manually and restarting unicorn.

Comment: If the image path is the only reason you need erb, I'd suggest scrapping erb and going with scss. An scss example of a solution to your problem would look like this: `background: image-url('hippopotamus.jpg') no-repeat; }`

Answer (score 5):

Here's what works:

It's fine to add .erb to .css files and use ruby/rails code. So the snippet in my question above is fine.

You have to add a line like this to your /config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile = ['*.css.erb']
```

Then when you run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
 the fingerprinted CSS file will get generated and the image_path will be correctly inserted.

So this solved my problem.

For me, .js files are getting precompiled automatically without me adding any config options. But css or css.erb files weren't working. So this is what I'm actually using:

```
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

Comment: For me, the `.erb` on the end of a specific file didn't work.  Here's an example of what worked for me (where foo and bar are .css.erb files: `config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css foo.css bar.css )`

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to precompile your assets. It's simple:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Everything will be run through Sprockets (the asset pipeline) and dumped into public/assets. Just make sure that gets deployed to production along with the rest of the app and that should be all!

Comment: So the snippet I showed in the question is correctly inside a `.css.erb` file provided that my asset pipeline is configured correctly? I'm simultaneously struggling with configuring the pipeline, so I'm trying to rule out variables.