# How to make Rails SASS generate a .css.erb file instead of a .css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I have never done anything like this before, so I'm not sure how to start going about it. Rails kindly compiles all my SASS files into one site-wide css file. I would like this file to be compiled as a .css.erb file.

Then the crazier part: I would also like to add a task to the compilation process, which looks for a particular token (perhaps just a string: "token") and replaces it with ruby/rails code. So if the sass would normally compile into this css:

`color: "token";`

I want it instead to compile to this:

`color: <%= current_user.primary_color %>;`

Is there any way to modify or add to the sass compilation process? Or is this a pipedream?

#### Background on the purpose of this request:

I have a site-builder in which users can choose 6 custom colors which will appear in various places of their website. The colors are saved as strings (like `"#123456"`). But since each user can change their color at any time, I need the flexibility of at least one css file not being included in SASS, so it can contain rails code to pull colors from the database (as mentioned above). I was really hoping I could incorporate this nightmare into the pipeline so it was more automatic.

Comment: You might want to look at these questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549069/get-sass-from-database-compile-passed-data-instead-of-reading-from-file or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558811/import-sass-file-from-database-instead-of-filesystem

Comment: The problem you are going to have is that these assets are dynamic. I solved it by using a separate css file(just to make it neater), then rendering that through a controller that processes it as erb, then as sass. I'll post as an answer if you think that would help.

Comment: Hi it is looking like you want please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704453/how-to-load-css-erb-files-through-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

a easy way would be to first get your scss.erb file into database and when you get it from the database it will go as compiled css maybe.